# AES256 hex_print to hex_tofile using enc_out

Tags: c, file

Given the variable enc_out as the output of an AES256 encryption algorithm, and the function:

```
static void hex_print(const void* pv, size_t len)
{
    const unsigned char * p = (const unsigned char*)pv;
    if (NULL == pv)
        printf("NULL");
    else
    {
        size_t i = 0;
        for (; i<len;++i)
            printf("%02X ", *p++);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Which is used to print the output AES256 encryption in hex, How can I change the above function to output the hex to a file?

Comment: I can't see any trace of C++ in this question, so I removed the tag...

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`fprintf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf) instead of `printf()`, and pass an additional `FILE *` parameter:

```
static void hex_print(FILE *out, const void* pv, size_t len)
{
     // ...
     fprintf(out, "%02X ", *p++);
     // ...
```

When calling this, pass an opened `FILE *` for `out`. You can also pass `stdout` or `stderr`, so this will be more flexible anyways.